# Pandas / pyplot histogram: can plot df but not subset

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

df is an enormous dataframe.  I only need the subset where Zcoord > 1.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(first)
df.columns = ['Xcoord', 'Ycoord', 'Zcoord', 'Angle']
df0 = df[df.Zcoord>1]
```

*The very same code* that will draw a histogram of df will not work for df0.

```
plot1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(df0.Zcoord, bins=100, normed=False)
plt.show()
```

Ipython spits out KeyError:0.

python 2.7.9 anaconda, ipython 2.2.0, OS 10.9.4

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-71643df3888f> in <module>()
      1 plot1 = plt.figure(1)
----> 2 plt.hist(df0.Zcoord, bins=100, normed=False)
      3 
      4 plt.show()
      5 from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, **kwargs)
   2888                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,
   2889                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,
-> 2890                       stacked=stacked, **kwargs)
   2891         draw_if_interactive()
   2892     finally:

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5560         # Massage 'x' for processing.
   5561         # NOTE: Be sure any changes here is also done below to 'weights'
-> 5562         if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):
   5563             # TODO: support masked arrays;
   5564             x = np.asarray(x)

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    482     def __getitem__(self, key):
    483         try:
--> 484             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    485 
    486             if not np.isscalar(result):

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1194 
   1195         try:
-> 1196             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1197         except KeyError as e1:
   1198             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2993)()

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2808)()

/Users/Kit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3440)()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `pandas.Series` to matplotlib (`df0.Zcoord`).  However, at the moment, matplotlib is a bit indecisive about whether or not it likes being fed pandas datatypes (as opposed to numpy `ndarray`'s).

At some point in the bowels of the matplotlib source, the histogram function is probably trying to get the "first item I've been asked to deal with", and it probably does that with a call to `input[0]` where `input` is whatever it was asked to chew on.  If `input` is a `numpy.ndarray` then everything works great.  However, if `input` is a `pandas.Series` or (even worse) a `pandas.DataFrame`, the expression `input[0]` will have a very different meaning.  In that case, depending on the structure of the data you fed to `plt.hist`, there could well be a `KeyError` when trying to index into your input.

In your particular case, this is probably working fine on `df` as a whole because `df` likely has an integer index (`[0, 1, 2, ..., len(df)-1]`), which is the default row index in a `DataFrame`.  However, when you select within `df` to make `df0`, the result keeps winds up with an index that is a subset of the index of `df` (maybe it winds up `[3, 6, 9, 12, ...]`).  So everything works fine on `df` (where the index contains `0`), but blows chunks on `df0` (where, ironically, given its name, `0` does not appear in the index).

Quick fix...instead of

```
plt.hist(df0.Zcoord, bins=100, normed=False)
```

run this

```
plt.hist(df0.Zcoord.values, bins=100, normed=False)
```

and my guess is everything will be good.

Comment: Glad it helped!  If you're interested, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5550) is thread where this issue is being discussed.  It would be great if you could include a bit more of the stack trace in your original post so that others can see exactly where the error comes from.